# Need to append data from one text file to a json file in linux

Tags: json

`file1.txt`:

```
{ "somedata": { "common_examples": [ { "text": "yes", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yep", "intent": "affirm" } ], "xyz_synonyms": [], "regex_features": []   } }
```

`file2.json`:

```
{      "name" : "jobname",      "pattern":"[A-Z]+-[0-9]"     },     {      "name" : "project",      "pattern":"[A-Z]{4}"    }
```

Output `file.json`:

```
{ "somedata": { "common_examples": [ { "text": "yes", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yep", "intent": "affirm" } ], "xyz_synonyms": [], "regex_features": [ {      "name" : "jobname",      "pattern":"[A-Z]+-[0-9]"     },     {      "name" : "project",      "pattern":"[A-Z]{4}"    } ]   } }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried? Remember Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Some effort on your part is expected.

Comment: Please also follow the [mcve] guidelines - if you are not going to give a precise statement of the requirements,  the example(s) should be minimal so that the requirements are obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Use `sed` stream editor

```
sed "s/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\": \[ $(cat file2.json) \]/g" file1.txt
```

Output

```
➜  ~  sed "s/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\": \[ $(cat file2.json) \]/g" file1.txt
{ "somedata": { "common_examples": [ { "text": "yes", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yep", "intent": "affirm" } ], "xyz_synonyms": [], "regex_features": [ { "name" : "jobname", "pattern":"[A-Z]+-[0-9]" }, { "name" : "project", "pattern":"[A-Z]{4}" } ] } }
```

This will work but it might not be elegant ;-)

Comment: I tried. but am getting the below error.
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unterminated `s' command

Comment: This is the command:
`sed "s/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\": \[ $(cat file2.json) \]/g" file1.txt`

Comment: use double quotes

Comment: command: sed "s/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\": \[ $(cat file2.json) \]/g" file1.txt

output: sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unterminated `s' command

Comment: command: sed 's/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\": \[ $(cat file2.json) \]/g' file1.txt

output: {
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "text": "yes",
        "intent": "affirm"
      },
      {
        "text": "yep",
        "intent": "affirm"
      },
      {
        "text": "yeah",
        "intent": "affirm"
      }
    ],
    "entity_synonyms": [],
    "regex_features": [ $(cat file2.json) ]
   }
 }

Comment: you're missing to escape the brackets `\[` and `\]`, command is: `sed "s/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\": \[ $(cat file2.json) \]/g" file1.txt`

Comment: command: `sed "s/\"regex_features\": \[\]/\"regex_features\":  \[ $(cat file2.json) 
 \]/g" file1.txt`

output: { "rasa_nlu_data": { "common_examples": [ { "text": "yes", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yep", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yeah", "intent": "affirm" } ], "entity_synonyms": [], "regex_features": [ $(cat file2.json) ] } }

Comment: output: { "rasa_nlu_data": { "common_examples": [ { "text": "yes", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yep", "intent": "affirm" }, { "text": "yeah", "intent": "affirm" } ], "entity_synonyms": [], "regex_features": [ **$(cat file2.json)** ] } } . 

Data is not getting replaced. please look at the bold part

Comment: let's stop pasting the command over and over again. it's working for me in Bash, are you using another interpreter? can you show me the output of `printenv SHELL`? what's your OS?

Comment: I am also using bash only. Output of `printenv SHELL` is /bin/bash and OS is ubuntu

Comment: am still getting the same error. data in file2.json is not getting appended in file1.